# Blackberry Simulator not rendering web page in the same fashion as physical device? (Z10)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

The web page [found here](http://seocial.ly/fifth) renders well in the BlackberryOS 10 Webkit browser within the VMWare Fusion simulator, but not on an actual device (I'm told, I don't have a physical Blackberry in front of me).

The first screenshot is what I'm told the page looks like on BlackberryOS 10, the second is what I see in the emulation. I tried it on all 6 device sizes provided by the Blackberry Simulator and it looks good.

**Edit: This seems to have something to do with the Blackberry Keyboard**

Ideas?

[image: On a Blackberry device]

[image: On the Blackberry Simulator (VMware)]

Comment: Can confirm the appears to be a width issue on a Z10, running 10.2.1.2102

Comment: And Q10 on 10.2.1.2102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blackberry keyboard seems to displace the size of the actual page outside of the viewport. **Opening the keyboard is the only way to replicate this issue** within the simulator.

I tried to compensate changing media queries to use the `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` properties as well as using units relative to the viewport (`vh` and `vw`), but it just wasn't perfect on all devices.

I used the following JavaScript to load a stylesheet for only BlackBerry devices:

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.match(/(BlackBerry|Blackberry|blackberry|BB|bb|RIM|rim|Playbook|PlayBook|playbook)/)!=null) { 
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blackberry.css">');
        console.log ('Blackberry confirmed'); 
    }
```

The only issue with this is that the Blackberry simulator's `userAgent` cannot be targeted with a regular expression because there's nothing unique about it. The code above does target all physical BlackBerry devices though.